# How to define a widget 'Var' in XML? (default it is defined 'Val')

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, android-livedata

For example, I changed a `TextView`'s text and text color used LiveData like below:

`xxxViewModel.class`:

```
val textViewText = MutableLiveData<String>()
val textViewTextColor= MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

`xxxFragment.class`:

```
xxxViewModel.textViewText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { binding.textView.text = it }
xxxViewModel.textViewTextColor.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { binding.textView.color= it }
```

But now I need to change almost all the properties of the `TextView`, so I figure maybe I observe `TextView` itself, rather than its properties, like below:

`xxxViewModel.class`:

```
val textView = MutableLiveData<TextView>()
```

`xxxFragment.class`:

```
// I got error here: says binding.textView is Val and cannot be reassign
xxxViewModel.textView.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { binding.textView = it }
```

`binding.textView` is a widget defined in XML, how can I change it from Val to Var?

Comment: You're doing wrong. Your 1st approach is right.

Comment: But for example, in above TextView case, if Text and TextColor properties always change at the same time. I would like to set them together, rather than set them separately.

Comment: No that's not possible